# Get nested reactive form value in Angular?

Tags: angular, forms, typescript

I have a nested form similar to the following:

```
profileForm = new FormGroup({
  firstName: new FormControl(''),
  lastName: new FormControl(''),
  address: new FormGroup({
    street: new FormControl(''),
    city: new FormControl(''),
    date1: new FormControl(''),
    date2: new FormControl('')
  })
});
```

I'm trying to set the `date2` mindate as `date1` value like this:

```
<mat-form-field class="datepickerformfield" floatLabel="never">
    <input matInput class="dp" formControlName="date2" [min]="profileform.controls['date1'].value" [matDatepicker]="date2" placeholder="DD/MM/AAAA" >
</mat-form-field>
```

Also tried with:

```
[min]="profileform.address.controls['date1'].value"
```

And

```
[min]="profileform.controls[address].controls['date1'].value"
```

But I get an error:

> Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

How can I get the `date1` value with the `profileform` object?

Comment: Can you share it in stackbiltz

Comment: `profileForm.get('address').get('date1')`

Comment: `[min]="profileform.get('address').get('date1').value"`, or `[min]="profileform.get('address.date1').value"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally solved with:

```
[min]="profileform.get('address.date1').value"
```

Working on Angular6+

Answer (score 0):

The form has am member called `value` which is a reflection of your form structure but only including the values.
To access the date you simply should call `[min]="profileform.value.address.date1"`.